# Macbook booting itself in to OS X Utilities

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, macbook, reinstall

Macbook (OS Mavericks) would not boot up last night, screen would go white, I'd see the apple logo and a loading bar which didnt move, then it would shut itself down after a few minutes.
I tried using Disk Utilities to verify the disk and repair the disk but nothing changed.
I next forced a fsck on the disk. 
Since then the mac just loads straight to OS X Utilites now when i press the power button.

Can somebody advise where I should go from here?
What I have available to me is:
1)Windows PC (Win 7)
2)Extrenal 1TB HDD
3)20gb Usb stick.
4)Macbook that is not booting.
5)Broadband connection

I though I could just the 'Install OS' over broadband feature(and save any data on the disk), but when I go in there it doesnt show the internal HDD as an option to install OSX again.
The 3 otions is shows are:
a)EFI 206.5mb
b)HD-PCU2 1TB (external HDD)
c)Recovery HD 650mb

Has anybody got any advice or tips on how to get OSX running again on this machine without wiping the disk. Failing that, is there a way to copy off any data that is on the disk elsewhere before going down the route of trying a reformat and partition on that drive to see if it is recoverable.

My important data is backed up to dropbox, so nothing tragic will be lost, but I'd still like to keep old emails and the likes if I can recover any of that.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this,
-C

Comment: Just a stab: Hold down the option key on boot and see if OSX is there in the list

Comment: I tried that and the only thing it shows is the recovery disc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "Target Mode"?
If you can get your hand on another Mac, you can try getting your stuff off before formatting the hard disk.
It may work with Windows machines, per the Wiki article below.
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode
Hope this helps you :-)